# React Native Android JavaScriptCore and LGPL license

Tags: react-native

quick question for anyone that may know. Are there any potential issues with using React Native on Android in regards to distributing JavaScriptCore libraries with your apk, since the JSC library is under LGPL license. I'm running into some questions myself so trying to find more on this topic, thanks in advance!